# Create a new vector based on conditions from an other vector

Tags: r

I have a vector

```r
v3 <- c(5, 4, 9, 0, 7, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 4, 9, 1, 8, 3, 1, 0)
```

How can I create a new vector with value TRUE if an element is equal to 0 and FALSE if it isn't equal to 0.

I should get this

```r
v3a <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

My first thought was using if and else functions but I'm unsure how to use them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `v3 == 0` should do the trick

Comment: @AllanCameron what would that look like? would it be something like `v3a <- if(v3 ==0, TRUE), ifelse (FALSE)`

Comment: Just `v3a <- v3 == 0`. Basically, R is asking the question to each element of the vector, is this element = 0?

Comment: If i wanted to solve 
Elements that are bigger than or equal to the value of subtracting the element in position 1 from the number 9,
`v3d <- v3 >= 9 - v3[1]` would this be an ok way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(v3==0, TRUE, FALSE)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```